# Como uso um Remote Event para duas coisas?

Tags: lua, lado-do-servidor

Eu estou tentando refazer um jogo de poderes no Roblox, estou usando uma place antiga Uncopylocked como base, e tudo lá é non-fe.

Eu queria usar só um evento remoto para vários códigos (já que todos são bem parecidos), mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso.
Esse é um script de exemplo, ele esta dentro de um botão.

```lua
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local Open = false
    function MouseClick()
        if Open == false then
            Open = true
            script.Parent.Text = "Learned"
            script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Flame Armor"):clone().Parent = player.Backpack -- Essa é a parte que eu usaria o remote
        end
        
    end
    script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(MouseClick)
```

Alguém poderia me dizer o que mandar no remote e o que colocar no script server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Bem... Voltei!
Ontem eu estava conversando com meu amigo sobre, até que chegamos em uma conclusão.

Primeiro nós criamos um evento no ReplicatedStorage chamado "Dar o bagulho" (Ele estava dentro de uma pasta)
Depois criamos uma pasta no ReplicatedStorage chamada Poderes
Aí colocamos o evento no LocalScript e mandamos ele enviar o caminho do Poder para o servidor

```
evento = game.ReplicatedStorage.Events["Dar o bagulho"] -- O evento
player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
Open = false
function MouseClick()
    if Open == false then
        Open = true
        script.Parent.Text = "Learned"
        evento:FireServer(game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Poderes").Phoenix) -- Envia o nome da pasta do poder para o servidor, nesse caso estamos fazendo com o Phoenix
    end
    
end
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(MouseClick)
```

Depois no script do servidor nós colocamos isso

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local itens = ReplicatedStorage.Poderes
local dador = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Events["Dar o bagulho"]

local function poder(client, nome) -- Client é o LocalPlayer, nome é o caminho que passamos pra ele
    local tool = itens:FindFirstChild(tostring(nome)) -- Da o find first child no nome da pasta do poder

     if tool then -- Se tudo der certo/Se ele achar
        tool:FindFirstChild("Flame Armor"):Clone().Parent = client.Backpack -- Ele procura a skill dentro da pasta e te da
    end
end

dador.OnServerEvent:Connect(poder)
```

Espero ter ajudado você, caso tinha a mesma dúvida que eu :)